# AsyncTask kill task when back button pressed

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am having a little problems with AsyncTask.

I have it implemented as follows

```
 private class MakeConnection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> implements OnDismissListener{

    Context context;
    ProgressDialog myDialog;
    public MakeConnection(Context conetext)
    {
        this.context = conetext;
        myDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.context);
        myDialog.setCancelable(true);
        myDialog.setOnDismissListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        //do stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            myDialog.dismiss();
            success(result);
        }catch(JSONException e)
        {
            data = e.toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            myDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Please wait...", "Loading the data", true);
       }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {

        this.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

But when ever I press the back button nothing happens, it just completes the task as if I didn't press the back button

Any idea why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two parts of this problem:

1) Implement your `doInBackground()` in such a way, so it checks whether `AsyncTask` is cancelled.

```
 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
       for(int i = 0; i < 100 && !isCancelled(); i++) { 
          //do some stuff
      }
}
```

2) You should call `asynTask.cancel(true)` in your Activity's `onDestroy()`.

Comment: I have a question about this now, I have implemented as you suggested but what I want to know is must I capture the back button event in the main UI thread or only in the AsyncTask onDesmiss method? Because when  I have a slow connection I can's cancel the AsyncTask with the current implementation

Comment: You should cancel `AsyncTask` in Activity's `onDestroy()`. When task is cancelled, `onPostExecute()` will not be called. In your case task will hang around for some time, but when finished, `AsyncTask.onCancelled()` is called (you can override it, of course). You should be careful only in this function (or just don't touch UI in from `onCancelled()`), because it can be called after Activity is already destroyed.

Comment: Ok if I leave the activity open for a while and the screen locks and then later unlock and resume using it, and try to start a new activity with a AsyncTask it just opens my dialog and nothing else happens, why is this?

Answer (score 4):

This fixes my problem

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){
    myDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
            context,
            "Please wait...",
            "Loading the data",
            true,
            true,
            new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    MakeConnection.this.cancel(true);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it is also possible to use follwing method in activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    imageLoadingAsyncTask.cancel(true);
}
```