# Android AsynchTask working while its calling Activity is finished

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My activity is finished while `AsynchTask` is inside `doinBackground()` method.

When it reaches `postExecute()` the activity used to update the UI is already destroyed,but its `TextView` is still accessible in `onPostExecute()`.
Can any one explain how this is happening?

Comment: when you finish the activity, you should cancel a `AsynchTask`(if it still running) too. please see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/7096045/5381331.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Activities have a specific lifecyle. When they go past their Destroy lifecycle state, **they are no longer usable by Android** and will be eventually garbage collected.

However, when you pass an Activity reference, or any widget reference for that matter, to an AsyncTask, this prevents the GC from dispossing the activity and its related objects (e.g. view and widgets). Furthermore, your AsyncTask, which is executed in a separate thread with its own state, will hold a reference one or more objects that are invalid. And since you hold a reference in your AsyncTask, they cannot be freed by the GC.

That is why you must be very careful with using AsyncTasks with Activity reference. Also, refrain from using AsyncTasks for updating your UI, there are other ways of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Before starting new activity call cancel on `AsyncTask`

```
asynTask.cancel(true)
```

and in your asynctasks `doInBackground` method check if `AsyncTask` is cancelled or not

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
   for( !isCancelled()) { 
      //do some stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question expects an explaination on how it happens.
Think of this simple java code.

```
public class myClass{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     int n=2;
     MyThread t=new MyThread(n);
     t.start();
     n=4;
     System.out.println("n from main "+n);
   }
}

class MyThread extends Thread{
    int n;
    public MyThread(int n){
        this.n=n;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }catch(Throwable e){
            System.out.println("error :"+e);
        }
        System.out.println("n from thread "+n);
    }
}
```

And the output would be,

```
n from main 4
n from thread 2
```

This happens because the instance of the integer n you pass to the thread holds its value. This is the same thing that happens in your AsyncTask. This behavior will be changed if you make n a static variable and made a reference to it inside the new thread.

Answer (score 0):

Your `activity` can get destroyed for several reasons such as

- System purging your `activity` due to memory needs
- You rotate the phone. Then the `Activity` gets killed and recreated
- You explicitly navigate back from the `Activity`

Your logic needs to handle such scenarios when executing an `AsyncTask`. Once your `Activity` starts an `AsyncTask`, it gets executed in another thread and delivers the results back to your `activity` once it gets finished. Your `activity` might get killed while the background `AsyncTask` is doing the work. A good practice is to call the `cancel(boolean)` method once your `activity` gets killed (onDestroy) and if you don't wish to continue with the results of the `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask (same as standard java thread) doesn't respect lifecycle of the host Activity. It's up to the developer to implement proper cancelling (as @mrDroid showed).

You may use AsyncTaskLoader, so you don't have to write code that handles activity configuration changes.

Be aware that even without direct reference to the host Activity (as mentioned @George Metaxas) a non-static inner AsyncTask may lead to memory leaks (because inner class holds implicit reference to the outer class).